# Drawing Lemniscate of Bernoulli

Tags: pgfplots, polar

I want to draw the [Lemniscate of Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli). Its polar equation is r^2=a^2\cos(2\theta), so it should be quite straightforward to plot.
Choosing a=2, I tried with the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[style=black!10,grid style=black!10,ticklabel style=black!50,enlargelimits=false, xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$]
    \addplot [thick, red, domain=0:360, samples=100] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the result is

[image]

which is not nice at all. Moreover, I also get a lot of errors similar to

```
NOTE: coordinate (1Y2.3272287e2],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).
```

I can improve the look of the plot by increasing the samples, but this increases compilation time and the number of errors without ever getting smooth enough.

I don't understand what is going on.

As a workaround, I can get a better looking figure using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[style=black!10,grid style=black!10,ticklabel style=black!50,enlargelimits=false, xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$]
    \addplot [thick, green, domain=-45:45, samples=100] {2*cos(2*x)};
    \addplot [thick, green, domain=135:225, samples=100] {2*cos(2*x)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the figure

[image]

From a qualitative point of view this is the same, but from the mathematical point of view it is a completely different thing and this is not satisfying.

Note that this figure compiles without errors and is quite smooth even with a small number of samples.

Comment: In your fist code, just change the number of samples: `samples=361` and you'll have it.

Comment: @JuanCastaño : You are right: it works. Yet, I do not understand why. And I still get lots of errors (178 of them, to be precise)

Comment: `samples=81,smooth` looks also fine.

Comment: You get the errors because of mathematics. `cos` of 90° to 270° is negative and the square route of a negative number is not defined (except in a complex plane) ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow: what a fool I have been... :(  Ok, I see that if I use two lines , one with `domain=-45:45` and the second with `domain=135:225`, then it compiles without errors. Is there a way to have a unique line (i.e., a domain which is the union of the two domains)?

Comment: I also note that this takes care of the number of samples: using `\addplot [thick, red, domain=-45:45, samples=100] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};` then the figure is always smooth regardless of the samples number (provided they are enough...)

Comment: Yes, you can use `samples at={-45,-40,-35,...,45,135,140,...,225}` instead of `domain`/`samples`. But to *always* get a smooth curve, you should add the option `smooth` as well.

Comment: And as an advice: You should use `\addplot+` (instead of `\addplot`) for debugging, i.e. to *see* where the samples *are*. From that you get a good idea what might be "wrong"/can be improved. When the plot is finished, you can remove the markers (again), if you don't need them. That would have helped you to find out why your first image looks that "distorted".

Comment: Thank you very much: if you want to write a full answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments below the question, you get the distorted result because you used improper sampling. You could have made this obvious by showing the markers (replace `\addplot` with `\addplot+`).

Then you would have seen that you need sampling points at all cos(*θ*) = 0 angles, i.e. 0°, 90°, 180°, 270°, to ensure that all features of the curve are visible. So the main task is to choose appropriate `domain` and `samples` values or *directly* state appropriate samples using `samples at`.

To ensure a smooth curve, add the `smooth` option.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        style=black!10,
        grid style=black!10,
        ticklabel style=black!50,
        enlargelimits=false,
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        % ensure a smooth curve
        smooth,
    ]
        % choose appropriate `domain` and `sample` values
        \addplot+ [
            thick,
            domain=-45:225,
            samples=55,
        ] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};

        % alternatively "manually" state the samples to use
        \addplot+ [
            samples at={-45,-40,-35,...,45,135,140,...,225},
        ] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]