# How to plot a lemniscate on the $xy$-plane with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

**Problem:** I want to graph the curve defined by the equation $\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2=x^2-y^2$ in the $xy$-plane.  I want to use pgfplots.

**My attempt:** I tried `\addplot {(x^2+y^2)^2=x^2-y^2}` but I am getting several errors about using $y$ in this context or using $=x$.

**Question:** Is there a workaround for plotting implicit equations?  Should I switch it to polar?  If so, can I graph a polar equation on the $xy$-plane?

**EDITED:** My solution was to use `\addplot [data cs=polar,domain=0:180,samples=361] (\x,{sqrt(cos(2*x))})`.  I found this idea in the manual in Section 4.23 on Transforming Coordinate Systems.  I also added a plot for the negative square root to plot the lower half of the curve.

Comment: See for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405305/52406). (But there are more).

Comment: [Does this answer your question or at least give you an idea?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629844/drawing-lemniscate-of-bernoulli)

Comment: @SebGlav Yes, but that is on a polar grid.  How would I adjust that to plot in the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, to draw implicit plots, we can try hard with TikZ/GNUplot/pgfplots (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471971/plotting-implicitly-in-tikz), for example). With Asymptote, it is straightforward.

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(5cm);       // size of figure   
import graph;    // module for xaxis, y axis, etc
import contour;  // module for contour

// define implicit function of the Lemnisace
real f(real x, real y) {return (x^2 + y^2)^2 -(x^2-y^2);}  
// the contour for f(x,y)=0
guide[][] pf = contour(f,(-1,-1),(1,1),new real[] {0});

// draw the first branch (here is the only branch)
draw(pf[0],blue+1pt);

xaxis("$x$",-1.2,1.4,Arrow(TeXHead));
yaxis("$y$",-.5,.6,Arrow(TeXHead));
```

Comment: Change the color from magenta to blue, please, and I'll accept the solution  :)

Comment: I suppose that you copy the code to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/, change the color from magenta to blue, and download pdf/png/etc yourself ^^

Comment: @UngarLinski see my update